# Create dictionary from list of tuples, wrong output

Tags: python

```
countries = [('AGO', 'ANGOLA'), ('PRT', 'PORTUGAL')]

countries_dict = {}
countries_new_list = []
for country_code, country in countries:
    print country_code
    countries_dict['country_code'] = country_code
    countries_new_list.append(countries_dict)

print countries_new_list
```

This code will print

```
AGO
PRT
[{'country_code': 'PRT'}, {'country_code': 'PRT'}]
```

And what i am expecting is:

```
AGO
PRT
[{'country_code': 'AGO'}, {'country_code': 'PRT'}]
```

What am I missing here?

http://codepad.org/nZblGER7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to define the dictionary `countries_dict` inside the for loop.

```
countries = [('AGO', 'ANGOLA'), ('PRT', 'PORTUGAL')]
countries_new_list = []
for country_code, country in countries:
    print country_code
    countries_dict = {}
    countries_dict['country_code'] = country_code
    countries_new_list.append(countries_dict)

print countries_new_list
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.  What's happening in the original code is that a reference to countries_dict is getting appended to countries_new_list each time through the list.  When you print the list, you get the current state of countries_dict however many times you appended it to the list.

Comment: `countries_dict['country_code'] = country_code` changes the value of the country_code key to the last item, since dict are mutable.

Answer (score 4):

Pythonic way by using **list compression**:-

```
>>> countries = [('AGO', 'ANGOLA'), ('PRT', 'PORTUGAL')]
>>> [{"country_code":i} for i ,j in countries]
[{'country_code': 'AGO'}, {'country_code': 'PRT'}]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error comes from the fact that you append the dictionnary `countries_dict` in `countries_new_list` and not a copy.

You should either do `countries_dict = {}` in the for loop or use a copy:

```
from copy import copy
...
countries_new_list.append(copy(countries_dict))
```